# Creating .shp from .dbf in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, shapefile, table, latitude-longitude

How do I create a shapefile using the latitude and longitude information in my dBASE table? I am using ArcMap 10.1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add your .dbf table into ArcMap and then create an XY event layer which you will be able to export to a shapefile.

Read more details here: [Adding x,y coordinate data as a layer](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s50000001z000000)

Answer (score 0):

Open ArcCatalog, and right click on the *.dbf file and select Create Feature Class from XY table. Then select X, Y fields in the dialog box including the coordinate system. Hit OK, then you get Event Layer in the contents. Right click in that and export data to shapefile, you are done.